# How to display JSX returned from other function inside return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a weather application using openweathermap api. As you can see below in the code, I use a boolean state to check when the form is summitted so I can pass that value to the `<Result>` component(which I checked with hard code and it works). I want the function `changeCity`(in the App) to return the `<Result>` component with the value of city passed and in the same time to change the `cityEmpty` state. But there I got the problem when I pass that in the return() `{(cityEmpty) ? changeCity() : null}`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Result from "./components/Result";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import './App.css';

function App() {
    
  const [city, setCity] = useState ("");
  const [cityEmpty, setCityEmpty] = useState(false);
  
  const changeCity = () => {
    setCityEmpty(false);
    return (<Result city={city}/>);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search city={city} setCity={setCity} cityEmpty={cityEmpty} setCityEmpty={setCityEmpty} 
      />
      {(cityEmpty) ? changeCity() : null}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react"

function Search({city, setCity, cityEmpty, setCityEmpty}){

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSumbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(cityEmpty);
    setCityEmpty(true);
    console.log(cityEmpty);
    setCity("");
  }

  return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSumbit}>
      <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Insert city"
      value={city}
      onChange = {handleInputChange}
      >
      </input>
    </form>
  </div>
);

}

export default Search
```

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clear about your _expected_ vs _actual_ results, please?  What actually happens when you do this? "I got the problem" doesn't describe what actually happened.

Comment: I don't expect `cityEmpty` to change just because you called `setCityEmpty(true)`, why are you logging `cityEmpty` it before and after `setCityEmpty`.  Are you expecting it to change?

Comment: I expect when the form is summitted to change the value of `cityEmpty` to true so I can know that the full name of city is entered. And when the value of `cityEmpty` is true I want to change it to false and return the `<Result />` and the pass the value of city.

Comment: ...And what actually happened?  (PS these are great details to include in the question itself, not just in comments.  Feel free to edit the question to include the extra details.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a state update inside the render of a component. Remember that whenever state is updated, it will re render the component. This will cause an infinite loop in your component.

1. Component renders
2. `changeCity` is called
3. Inside `changeCity`, `setCityEmpty` is called
4. Go back to step 1 for rendering.

Instead, consider checking if `city` is empty in your `handleInputChange` and calling `setCityEmpty` inside that function.

EDIT: To clarify a function that returns a component is completely fine, this is all components are really. Functions (or in previous react versions: classes) returning other components.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to return JSX from function. In your case it is pretty straightforward to use.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Result from "./components/Result";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import './App.css';

function App() {
    
  const [city, setCity] = useState ("");
  const [cityEmpty, setCityEmpty] = useState(false);
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search city={city} setCity={setCity} cityEmpty={cityEmpty} setCityEmpty={setCityEmpty} 
      />
      {cityEmpty && <Result city={city}/>}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


import React from "react"

function Search({city, setCity, cityEmpty, setCityEmpty}){

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSumbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(cityEmpty);
    setCityEmpty(true);
    console.log(cityEmpty);
    setCity("");
  }

  return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSumbit}>
      <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Insert city"
      value={city}
      onChange = {handleInputChange}
      >
      </input>
    </form>
  </div>
);

}

export default Search
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem you're seeing is but I noticed you're setting state inside of a render function, which is a bad pattern. Any state changes will trigger a re-rendering of the component and if you set state within a render function then you'd have an infinite loop of re-renderings (but.

Try removing `setCityEmpty(false)` in `changeCity`.

```
const changeCity = () => {
  return (<Result city={city}/>);
}
```

So how would you update cityEmpty? It's not clear what the end goal is here. With more info, we can find a better implementation.